# How can I syncronize SqlServerEdge running on linux with AzurSQL

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-iot-edge

Client runnig  SQL Edge on rasberry pi using Linux (Raspian)
What is the best practice  to sync database with Azure SQL?
As I see Dabase sync  working only on Windows?
Are there any linux sync agent?

Comment: Hi @sazbolcs, If my answer is helpful for you, please accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, SQL Data Sync only works on windows.

Just for now, there isn't a linux sync agent. Some others have post a [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217321-sql-database/suggestions/39474382-linux-version-of-sql-data-sync), but still with no responce:
[image]

We can continue to vote it up to let the Azure SQL product team see it.

HTH.